# Online docs for getTwilioClient() as used in "Functions and Assets"

Tags: twilio, twilio-functions

I have found a few examples of `context.getTwilioClient()`, but I have not been able to locate any online documentation. It's probably right under my nose, but it is eluding me. In particular, I'm trying to get information about workers in a Task Router queue (i.e., how many workers are in the different statuses and how many workers are available), but having the documentation will help with future projects.

I found some documentation saying that the `context.getTwilioClient()`, "enables you to invoke the getTwilioClient method on the context object for a fully-initialized Twilio REST API client." (https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115007737928-Getting-Started-with-Twilio-Functions)

It then shows this example, but there is no implementation of "messages" when I attempt to run this code:

```
var client = context.getTwilioClient();
client.messages.create({
  to: '+12025551212',
  from: '+12065551212',
  body: "hello world!"})
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `messages` property should be on the client. `getTwilioClient` returns [the Twilio helper library for Node.js](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/node).

I just created a Function with your code, and it worked as expected, meaning that I got the SMS, however, the function did time out because the `callback` was never invoked. To end the function invocation and respond to the caller, make sure you always invoke the `callback` function, like this:

```js
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  var client = context.getTwilioClient();
  client.messages.create({
    to: '+1xxxxxxxxxx',
    from: '+1xxxxxxxxxxx',
    body: "hello world!"})
  .then((message) => {
    console.log('SMS successfully sent');
    console.log(message.sid);
    // Make sure to only call `callback` once everything is finished, and to pass
    // null as the first parameter to signal successful execution.
    return callback(null, `Success! Message SID: ${message.sid}`);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    return callback(error);
  });
};
```

You can [learn more about the `callback` function here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/serverless/functions-assets/functions/invocation#callback-function).

If you still encounter this issue, can you tell use what Node Version you're using and which module dependencies and their versions?

You can find these details at **Settings & More** > **Dependencies** in your Twilio Functions Service.

Comment: I am 100% baffled and confused. Under "Functions and Assets", I have a service with two functions.

When editing the first (from a few days ago), if I type `client.me` the autocomplete displays only `message`.

I created a new function and copied your code, updating the phone numbers, and when I type `client.me`, the autocomplete shows both `message` and `messages`.

I copied the code from the first function into the second and I only have one autocomplete, `message`.

Since they're in the same service, they are both using Node.js v14, although changing to v16 makes no difference.

Comment: The other modules are the standard ones added when creating the service. lodash 4.17.11, twili 3.29.2, xmldom 0.1.27, @twilio/runtime-handler 1.0.1, and util 0.11.0 .

Comment: I see, so is it the autocompletion that isn't working, or does the given code not work at all?

Comment: I believe it is an issue with auto-completion. I created a third function, hand typing the lines and when I got to the line beginning with `client.me`, there were no auto-completion options. I continued typing the function, saved and deployed it, and it operated correctly by sending the SMS message. Going back to the third function, and now typing `client.me` showed both `message` and `messages`. So, it appears that the autocomplete doesn't work until the function is saved and deployed first, and only if the function already contains `client.messages`.

Comment: Interesting! So maybe the modules are only pulled down when it is deployed, and then the autocomplete starts working because the modules are now present. I'll pass on this feedback.

Comment: Cool, thanks. If I could go back to the original message. Early on, you mentioned the Twilio helper library for Node.js. I ended up in a circular loop, clicking links and returning to the same pages. Can you send a link to the documentation for client.messages (for example), which I have not found. I'm ultimately looking for documentation on the methods and attributes for the client object, not just messages.

Comment: You can find [the docs for the node library here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/reference/twilio-node/). Then select the version you're using, let's say [3.84.0](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/reference/twilio-node/3.84.0/), then click on [the `Twilio` class](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/reference/twilio-node/3.84.0/Twilio.html) where you can find your `messages` property. That takes you to [the `MessagesList` class](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/reference/twilio-node/3.84.0/Twilio.Api.V2010.AccountContext.MessageList.html) where you can find the `create` method

Comment: It's not that easy to find, but I hope this helps!

Comment: That helped; thank you! I missed clicking on the Twilio class, so I never saw anything further into the hierarchy.

Comment: If this answers your question, kindly accept it! We can't wait to see what you build!